# Why is my angularjs check-box custom directive not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my app I make frequent use of a checkbox. Given the repetitiveness I wanted to make a custom directive out of it, but when I call the directive in my html it does not check the checkbox. I cannot figure out what I am missing. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
    <input type="checkbox"
       class="form-control"
       name="{{attrs.name}}" 
       id="{{attrs.id}}"
       data-ng-model="model">
    <label for="{{attrs.id}}">
        <span>{{labelText}}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.directives')
    .directive('ccCheckBox', checkbox);

checkbox.$inject = [];
/* @ngInject */
function checkbox() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            labelText: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: './src/_directives/checkbox.html',
        link: CheckBox
    };
    function CheckBox(scope, attrs){
        activate();

        function activate(){
            scope.attrs = attrs;
        }
    }
}
})();
```

**Called in my code as** 
..

```
 <cc-check-box 
      data-label-text="Test CheckBox Label"
      data-name="checkBoxGrp"
      data-id="myCheckBox"
      data-for="myCheckBox"
      data-ng-model="vm.model.myCheckBoxValue">
 </cc-check-box>
```

No errors in the dev tools console.

Comment: First mistakes I could see is function CheckBox and activate is referenced before they are define. Console must be throwing undefined symbol errors

Comment: I can see you missed to close the input tag.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure It's at the end of the data-ng-model attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set *data-ng-model* to bind with *model* attr.

You should use **model** (as you defined into the isolated scope) or **data-model**.

```
<cc-check-box 
    data-label-text="Test CheckBox Label"
    data-name="checkBoxGrp"
    data-id="myCheckBox"
    data-for="myCheckBox"
    data-model="vm.model.myCheckBoxValue"
></cc-check-box>
```